# Long shot: 90's ish dystopian sci-fi with female lead

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

I have a very vague memory of a book which nonetheless managed to stick in my brain. I would have read it somewhere in the vicinity of junior high in the early/mid 90's, and it was probably relatively new at the time. What I recall of the cover is dark colors - black, blue, etc - featured a girl gazing outward, as if into space. I think I recall a large ship visible in the background, perhaps roundish in shape.

Possible plot elements, though perhaps conflated with other books: living in a dome city; perhaps about to be on an expedition in space; perhaps the protagonists father is in a position of some authority.

I'm partly curious to find this book simply to try and remember why it has stuck in my mind for as long as it has.

Answer (score 7):

Could it be the 1996 novel ***Starborne*** by Robert Silverberg?  Here is one of several different covers for it:

[image]

The novel concerns an *expedition into space* that goes awry.  The main character, who we see on the cover, is Noelle.  I'm not sure if there is a domed city, but the setting is dystopian: Earth faces a crisis as a long period of Utopia has actually decayed the will of humans to live.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but afraid that's not it. I should have left my date range at early 90's, though the book could have even come out in the mid/late 80's.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a conflation of two books by Monica Hughes: [Keeper of the Isis Light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Keeper_of_the_Isis_Light) and [Devil On My Back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_on_My_Back).

One of the covers for Keeper of the Isis Light looks a bit like your description:
[image: Keeper of the Isis Light]

Living in a dome city and the protagonist's father in a position of authority are both plot elements from Devil On My Back.

Both books are from the 1980s but I was reading them in the early 90s.